# ¿Como capturo la fecha en mi INSERT INTO?

Tags: php, json, mysqli, datatables

Necesito insertar la fecha y la sesión a mi BD.

```
<?php

include("conecta.php");

$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$razon = $_POST["razon"];
$arregloIds = $_POST["idsSeleccionados"];
$comentarios = $_POST["comentarios"];



$insertar = "INSERT INTO reporte (fecha, razon, comentarios) VALUES ('$fecha','$razon','$comentarios')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

if ($resultado) {
    $idReporte = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);
    for ($i = 0; $i<count($arregloIds); $i++) {
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO pedidos_reportes(id_usuario, id_reporte, id_pedido, fecha_modificacion) VALUES ( '1', '$idReporte','$arregloIds[$i]', 'now()') "; // En esta linea quiero que la fecha se ponga la actual
        $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    }

    if ($resultado2) {
       
        echo json_encode(true);
    }
}else {
    echo json_encode(false);
}
```

En mi codigo muestro como agrego el `now()` pero cuando reviso el registro, la fecha sigue apareciendo en 0000 00 00.

Son dos tablas distintas.
Porfavor si alguien me puede ayudar, Gracias.

[image: Estas son mis tablas]

Comment: El campo es tipo DATE

Comment: Es `NOW()` sin las comillas, es decir, cambiar esto `, 'now()')`  por esto `, now())`. De lo contrario le estas pasando la cadena `"now()"` en lugar del valor devuelto por la función `NOW()`

Comment: Es correcto, ya corregi esa parte @Marcos Muchas gracias, me has salvado!

Comment: Si el campo va a guardar solo año-mes-dia entonces en lugar de now yo pensaría en cambiarlo por curdate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes coloccar el Now() sin las comillas simples. Aunque en SQL tanto las fechas como horas se escriben entre comillas, al utilizar una función, y en concreto la función NOW, las comillas no son necesarias. La solución quedaría así en tu línea de código:

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO pedidos_reportes(id_usuario, id_reporte, id_pedido, fecha_modificacion) VALUES ( '1', '$idReporte','$arregloIds[$i]', 'insert datetimesql now' NOW()) ";
```